# Why does a joined list have to be inside a non-capturing group for the regex to be able to interpret it?

Tags: python, regex

So I'm trying to build a regex that searches for an occurrence of digits followed by a white space following by one of many possible key words (represented by `test_cases` in this case).

The first regex below does that successfully however I'm confused as to why it works. My understanding of capturing groups is that they allow you to put quantifiers on the group and also assist in specifying what data is returned. Why does this example need to be in the non-capturing group for it to be processed correctly?

```
test_string = "251 to 300 Vitality"
test_cases = ["Damage", "Pods", "Chance", "Vitality"]

print(re.findall(r'\d+\s(?:{})$'.format('|'.join(test_cases)), test_string)) # works
print(re.findall(r'\d+\s({})$'.format('|'.join(test_cases)), test_string)) # doesn't work
print(re.findall(r'\d+\s{}$'.format('|'.join(test_cases)), test_string)) # doesn't work
```

Output:

```
['300 Vitality']                                                                                                                      
['Vitality']                                                                                                                          
['Vitality']
```

Comment: Because `re.findall()` is documented as behaving differently depending on the number of capturing groups.  0: returns the overall match, 1: returns that group only, 2+: returns a tuple of all groups.

Comment: Shouldn't the third case still return the desired output of "300 Vitality" in that case, or is something wrong with my regex there?

Comment: In your third regex, the `\d+\s` is part of the first alternative only, and the `$` is part of the last alternative only.

Comment: Another way of looking at #3 is it matches "Vitality" regardless of whether it is preceded by digits.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference in regex behavior between Perl and Python?](/q/757476/90527)